# What leads us to believe that 2+2 is equal to 4?

Tags: arithmetic, philosophy

My professor of Epistemological Basis of Modern Science discipline was questioning about what we consider knowledge and what makes us believe or not in it's reliability.

To test us, he asked us to write down our justifications for why do we accept as true that 2 plus 2 is equal to 4. Everybody, including me, answered that we believe in it because we can prove it, like, I can take 2 beans and more 2 beans and in the end I will have 4 beans. Although the professor told us: "And if all the beans in the universe disappear", and of course he can extend it to any object we choose to make the proof. What he was trying to show us is that the logical-mathematical universe is independent of our universe.

Although I was pretty delighted with this question and I want to go deeper. I already searched about Peano axioms and Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms although I think the answer that I am looking for can't be explained by an axiom.

It is a complicated question for me, very confusing, but try to understand, what I want is the background process, the gears of addition, like, you can say that a+0=a and then say a+1 = a+S(0) = S(a+0) = S(a). Although it doesn't show what the addition operation itself is. Can addition be represented graphically? Like rows that rotates, or lines that join?

Summarizing, I think my question is: How can I understand addition, not only learn how to do it, not just reproduce what teachers had taught to me like a machine. How can I make a mental construct of this mathematical operation?

Comment: If it can't be explained by the axioms, perhaps it's not really a mathematical question, and should be asked on/migrated to philosophy.SE?

Comment: Is there a difference between "I can take 2 beans and 2 more beans and in the end I will have 4 beans", and "2+2=4"? The second statement is a theorem. We have some definitions, and some axioms, and using them we can prove this. That "2+2=4" is true essentially means that from a standard set of axioms using standard rules of inference we can produce a formal proof of this statement. The first one seems to be an observation about the real world. Observations about the real world are empirical facts, they cannot be proved. Is the question about the relation between these 2 statements?

Comment: More concretely to the point, if you are a Platonist and mathematics "exists in an independent universe", then it doesn't matter what leads us to believe that $2+2=4$, since it is either true or false and we will never really know (only believe in one outcome or another). But if you have any doubts in the Platonist approach, then there's no real way to develop mathematics without axioms, if you doubt there is a universe of math out there, axioms and inference rules is all you have. In that case, agreeing that natural numbers are described by Peano Axioms is enough to show that $2+2=4$.

Comment: I don't think that bridge exists. If you are looking for it you will have to study mathematics for its own sake, or else you will always have some half-assed notion that you "understand mathematics", even though you will probably be wrong about that. The only way to build that bridge is from the mathematical side, regardless to prior philosophical education (which can surely help, of course).

Comment: There's more to life than Peano axioms.  You can define the natural numbers (and addition) geometrically rather than as sets, as points on a line.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I completely agree with you, by one way you have to simply believe in it and there will be no way to really judge its reliability, by another way it would be necessary to use axioms. I am satisfied with this now. But now I am still looking for an answer for the last paragraph, can the operation be represented? And can we have a graphical construct about it?

Comment: @vadim123: You can also define the natural numbers using some weak fragments of Peano axioms. The question is what you are going to do with it. If you only want to prove that $2+2=4$ then you can define some very finite list of axioms and get it over with. But if you agree that the natural numbers are useful for induction, then there is no real escape from PA.

Comment: Mathematics did just fine for a long time without induction or PA.

Comment: @vadim: True, it did. It also did fine without any axioms. Oh wait, what's that Bishop Berkeley? There *is* a problem? Oh, wait, Abraham Robinson and Jerzy Los are on the other line. It turns out that there isn't an actual problem **if one sticks to the axioms**. Also, the fact that one uses fire before the term "fire" is introduced does not mean that one did not use fire before that.

Comment: @Asaf, see my answer. We cannot discard the contribution of Jacques Derrida.

Comment: It seems to me that, if all the beans in the universe were to vanish, the fact that $2+2=4$ would survive unscathed, but the familiar connection between addition and bean-counting would have to be discarded or at least revised.  In other words, mathematics is not about beans but about abstract patterns that may or may not have physical realizations.  Patterns can remain even if their physical realizations get ruined.

Comment: When the beans disappear, we can still *imagine* the beans. Or any other objects. And when our imagination disappears? Well, then we still can count our thoughts. And if the thoughts disappear as well? Well, then there's nobody left who could ask the question.

Comment: While beans may disappear, processes may not, and if a process can be repeated then the natural numbers can be considered as counts of the number of iterations of a fixed process $f$. You can define addition via $f^{m+n} = f^m \circ f^n$ and can convince yourself that addition is commutative and associative with identity $0$ because $f^0$ is "do nothing". Similarly you can define multiplication  via $f^{m \times n} = (f^m)^n$, and can convince yourself that multiplication is commutative and associative with identity $1$ because $f^1 = f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always liked this approach, that a naming precedes a counting.

===============================================

[image]

================================================

Comment: Thanks, your answer combined to the comments on my question clarified my mind about this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Take the set $2=\{0,1\}$ (this is indeed $2$, nothing more, nothing less) and consider the set $A:=2\times \{0\}\cup 2\times \{1\}$ (two disjoint copies of 2). The number of elements (the cardinality) of such a set is (one of the possibility for) what we mean by $2+2$ and such a set has exactly four elements, i.e. there's a bijection between $A$ and $4=\{0,1,2,3\}$. This is why $2+2=4$, I'd say.

Comment: I find that much less persuasive than the argument about the beans.